# )''') sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Tags: python, sql

I'm creating a simple table using sqlite3's library, but I get this error:

> )''') sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

The code used is:

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE variable (id_variable INTEGER, name_variable TEXT, type_variable TEXT, id_ref_place INTEGER,
                PRIMARY KEY (id_variable),
                FOREIGN KEY (id_ref_place)
                )''')
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is:

```sql
FOREIGN KEY(<your_attr>) REFERENCES <OTHER_TABLE>(<other_table_attr>)
```